# how to render current_user after login to a Bootstrap input form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This might have already been asked, working on a ruby on rails bcrypt // authentication project that I am testing different methods for checking user login both in the view, and within an bootstrap form. but I am however having trouble trying to render my user controller current_*user :id (after login) to (render) prefill an input form value*

*what I am trying to do is have my controller or modal change the value of "@helloguy123"  in the plaintext field with my current_user*(params[:id]) to show my user is login to a dashboard page and prefills this value space with user ID, so if the user wants to "change password" they are login to there user space, and my form check shows true that they are login, and ID of the user is showing on the page.

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/users/', to: 'user#index'
  get '/users/:id', to: 'user#show'
  get '/register/',  to: 'register#index'
  get '/checkuser/', to: 'user#validate'
  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  get '/', to: 'home#index'
  get '/dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index'

  post '/register/', to: 'register#createuser'  
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'

end
```

user controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
   def index
    # rendering json on page: user data
      render json: User.all
   end

   def create
      user = User.new(
         first_name: params[:fname], 
         last_name: params[:lname],
         username: params[:username],
         password: params[:password],
         password_confirmation: params[:password_confirmation]
      end

   def show
      #  render plain: params[:id]
      #render json: userdata[:users].select {|user| user.get_id() == params[:id].to_i}
      if User.exists?(params[:id])
         render json: User.find(params[:id].to_i)
      else 
         render plain: "that user doesnt exist: #{params[:id]}"
      end
   end

   def validate
      puts params
      username = params[:username]
      exists = User.exists?(username: username)
      # puts exists
      render json: {"exists": exists, "username": username}
   end
end
```

input form I am using from bootstrap

```
<% content_for :content do %>

<form class="row g-3">
 <div class="col-auto">
  <label for="username" class="visually-hidden"></label>
  <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="username" value="@Helloguy123">
 </div>
 
 <div class="col-auto">
 <label for="password" class="visually-hidden">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
 </div>

 <div class="col-auto">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Confirm identity</button>
 </div>
</form>

<% end %>

<%= render template: "layouts/application" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you already have `current_user` helper

So you can use it

```
<input
  type="text"
  readonly
  class="form-control-plaintext"
  id="username"
  value="<%= current_user&.username || "@Helloguy123" %>"
>
```